# método que retorne Verdadero si el dato q sale de la Cola está en la Pila sino retorne Falso

Tags: java, poo, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

```
   package evaluacion.parcial.pkg1;
   import java.io.IOException;
   public class EvaluacionParcial1 {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Cola cola=new Cola();
    Pila pila = new Pila();
    //Elementos en la Pila:
    System.out.println("Elementos en la Pila");
    pila.Imprimir();

    System.out.println("Elementos en la Pila despues de quitar un elemento:");
    pila.Pop();
    pila.Imprimir();

    System.out.println("Elementos en la COLA");
    cola.Imprimir();

    System.out.println("Elementos en la COLA despues de quitar un elemento:");
    cola.Avanzar();
    cola.Imprimir();

    }
}






package evaluacion.parcial.pkg1;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.Random;

public class Pila {
public static final int MAX_LENGTH = 5;
public static String Pila[] = new String[MAX_LENGTH];
public static int cima = -1;
public static String Pilaaux[] = new String[MAX_LENGTH];
public static int cimaaux = -1;
Pila()
{
   LlenarPila();
}
public void Push(String dato)
{
  if ((Pila.length-1)==cima){
    System.out.println("Capacidad de la pila al limite");
  }else{
        cima++;
        //System.out.println("Cima en la posición "+cima);
        Pila[cima]=dato;
  }
}
public void PushAux(String dato){
  if ((Pilaaux.length-1)==cimaaux){
    System.out.println("Capacidad de la pila auxiliar al limite");
  }else{
     cimaaux++;
     Pilaaux[cimaaux]=dato;
   }
}
public boolean VaciAaux(){
    return (cimaaux==-1);
}
public boolean Vacia(){
    if (cima==-1){
        return (true);
    }
    else {
        return(false);
    }
}
public String Pop(){
  String quedato;
  if(Vacia()){
      System.out.println("No se puede eliminar, pila vacía !!!" );
      return("");
  }else{
          quedato=Pila[cima];
      Pila[cima] = null;
      --cima;
          return(quedato);
        }
}
public String PopAux(){
  String quedato;
  if(cimaaux== -1){
        System.out.println("No se puede eliminar, pila vacía !!!" );
        return("");
  }else{
          quedato=Pilaaux[cimaaux];
      Pilaaux[cimaaux] = null;
      --cimaaux;
          return(quedato);
       }
}

private boolean PilaLlena()
{
    if ((Pila.length-1)==cima)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

private boolean PilaLlenaAux()
{
    if ((Pilaaux.length-1)==cimaaux)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

private void LlenarPila()
{
    Random random= new Random();
    int numero;
    do {
       numero = random.nextInt((50 - 1) + 1 ) +1;
            Push(String.valueOf(numero));

    }while(!PilaLlena());
}

 public void Imprimir(){
  String quedata,salida=" ";
  if (cima!=-1)
  { 

      do {
        quedata = Pop();
        salida=salida+quedata+" - "; //System.out.println mostrando
        PushAux(quedata);            
    }while(cima!=-1);
    do {
        quedata=PopAux();
        Push(quedata);
    }while(cimaaux!=-1);
    System.out.println(salida);
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, salida);
  }
  else {
      System.out.println("La pila esta vacía");

  }
 }
 }





 package evaluacion.parcial.pkg1;

 import java.util.Random;

 public class Cola{
 String[] ArregloCola;
    int primero=-1,ultimo=-1; //declaración cola principal
    String[] ArregloColaux; 
    int primeroaux=-1,ultimoaux=-1; //declarar cola auxiliar
 int Cant_elem=10;
    int Cant_elem2=10; //tamaño del arreglo cola

//Constructor
Cola(){
    ArregloCola=new String[Cant_elem];
            ArregloColaux =new String[Cant_elem2];
            primeroaux=-1;
    ultimoaux=-1;
    primero=-1;
    ultimo=-1;

            LlenarCola();

}

private void LlenarCola() 
{
    Random random= new Random();
    int numero;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        numero = random.nextInt((50 - 1) + 1 ) +1;
            Ingresar(String.valueOf(numero));
    }


}


    public boolean ColaLlena(){
        //primero y último en los extremos
        if ((primero==0)&&(ultimo==Cant_elem-1)) 
            return(true);
        if (ultimo+1==primero) //último más uno alcanza a primero
            return (true);
        return(false);
    }

//Encola un elemento
public void Ingresar(String x)
    {
    if(VaciaCola()) 
            {
                    primero++;
        ultimo++;
                    //en la posición de último en ArregloCola se
                    //guarda el dato X
        ArregloCola[ultimo]=x; 
        }
    else{
        if(ColaLlena())
            System.out.println("No hay campo");
        else
                        if (ultimo==Cant_elem-1)
                            ultimo=0;
                        else
                            ultimo++;
                    ArregloCola[ultimo]=x;
        }
}


//Desencola un elemento
public String Avanzar(){
        String dato=null;
    if(VaciaCola())
        System.out.println("No hay Elementos");
    else{
                dato=ArregloCola[primero];
                if (primero == ultimo){
                    primero=-1;
                    ultimo=-1;
                    }
                else{
                    if (primero==Cant_elem-1)
                        primero=0;
                    else
                        primero++;
                }
    }
        return(dato);
}

public void Ingresaraux(String x)
    {
    if(ultimoaux==-1)
            {
        ultimoaux++;
                    primeroaux++;
        ArregloColaux[ultimoaux]=x;
    }
    else{
        ultimoaux++;
        if(ultimoaux==Cant_elem2)
            System.out.println("No hay campo");
        else
            ArregloColaux[ultimoaux]=x;
        }
}

public String Avanzaraux(){
        String dato=null;
    if(VaciaColaux())
        System.out.println("No hay Elementos");
    else{
                dato=ArregloColaux[primeroaux];
                if (primeroaux == ultimoaux){
                    primeroaux=-1;
                    ultimoaux=-1;
                    }
                else{
                    primeroaux++;
                }
    }
        return(dato);
}

//Retorna si esta vacia la cola
public boolean VaciaColaux(){
    return (ultimoaux==-1 && primeroaux==-1);
}

//Retorna si esta vacia la cola 2
public boolean VaciaCola(){
    return (ultimo==-1 && primero==-1);
}

   public void Imprimir(){
    String desplazar2;
    if(VaciaCola())
        System.out.println("No hay Elementos");
    else{
        //System.out.println("La cola es: ");
        while(!VaciaCola()){
            desplazar2=Avanzar();

            Ingresaraux(desplazar2);
        }
        while(!VaciaColaux()){
            desplazar2=Avanzaraux();
            System.out.print(desplazar2+" - ");
            Ingresar(desplazar2);
        }
        System.out.println("");
}
}


}
```

Comment: Hola Alisson, binenvenida a [es.so]. Sería genial si contextualizas el problema y das una mejor explicación para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte. De paso léete [ask]

Comment: de paso, aprovecha y hace el [tour]. Y mas alla que el titulo tiene que ser descriptivo de cual es el error, en la pregunta debes detallar donde esta el problema. ver todo tu programa no es de ayuda.

Comment: Tendrias que implementar un metodo que busque un dato dentro de la pila, ya que tu metodo Avanzar() ya retorna el dato que sale de la Cola